# Finalize is not called after error in Angular 8 app

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I'm trying to build an angular-app in Angular 8, where I get from a backend an Observable and want to subscribe to it. This is my code I already have:

```
this.employeesService.getEmployees$()
      .pipe(
        tap(employees => {
          this.employees = employees;
          console.log(this.employees.length);
        }),
        catchError(err => this.error = err),
        finalize(() => {
          console.log(this.error);
          this.isOperationInProgress = false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

```
this.employeesService.getEmployees$()
```

This function returns an Observable, with which I want to make multiple things.

When I try to reach the backend, but its offline, I get nothing as a return-value of my function. So here's my problem:

When this happens, I try to call the finalize-function. But this function does not get called after an error.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: catchError have to return observable

Comment: @DamianPioś so I just can return my this.employees there?

Comment: `tap` won't be fire if error occure, so `employees` will be `undefined`, you can return sth like `of(error.message)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank you for your question.

[The official definition](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) of `catchError()` operator is:

> Catches errors on the observable to be handled by returning a new observable or throwing an error.

Or in other words, the main idea of this operator is to return a new observable in case if some error has happened. I can provide a code example with business logic if you want.

The idea of the [`finalize()` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html) is to provide a possibility to start side-effects after Observable was completed. Because of the error or just complete.

So, in case if you want to show an error message when your BE service is unavailable your code should be something like:

```js
this.isOperationInProgress = true;
// I do not recommend the '$' symbol for service methods. But, it's up to you
this.employeesService.getEmployees().pipe(
   tap(console.log),
   finalize(() => this.isOperationInProgress = false)
).subscribe(
    employees => this.employees = employees, 
    error => this.showErrorMesage(error.message)
)
```

If you are interested in more detailed explanations: ***Here is a great [blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) post*** about error handling.

I hope it was useful. I would like to hear any kind of feedback from you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is also working. Do I have to return something in the `this.showErrorMessage()` or not?

Comment: Sorry about such a long answer. In case if you catch an error with a second param in the `subscribe` method you should provide only a callback with a signature `(e: error) => void`. So, nothing should be returned from this function. Have a great day! Thank you for feedback.

Comment: will finalize() work if error => {} block within subscribe() is omitted? E.g. I'm interested in positive outcome only, all other outcomes should be handled within finalize(). Thanks

Comment: @tillias Not sure that I got your point correctly. Yes, it should work even if the error part in the `subscribe()` is missing. But, in case if you don't subscribe the whole pipe won't be executed. E.g. request won't send.

P.S. If you want to try out some things like this assumption you can check it on StackBlitz with rxjs playground.

Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is more idiomatic to RxJS to have your results be stored in the subscribe instead of storing intermediate values as 'side-effect' using `tap` or `catchError`. This is mainly because side-effects are more difficult to test in isolation.

```
this.employeesService.getEmployees$()
.pipe(
    take(1)
)
.subscribe(
    employees => {
        this.employees = employees;
        this.isOperationInProgress = false;
    },
    error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.isOperationInProgress = false;
    }
);
```

That beeing said; The reason why your finalize is not invoked is because the catchError should always return an Observable, not `void`.

Comment: So if I would add a return-statement to my catchError, it would work? should I then return a new Observable or the employees?

Answer (score 0):

I made it myself. I just changed the catchError-clause and the finalize-clause.

```
this.employeesService.getEmployees$()
      .pipe(
        tap(employees => {
          this.employees = employees;
          console.log(this.employees.length);
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.isOperationInProgress = false;
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          this.error = err;
          return this.employees;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

But thanks for the help.